# Can we change reset password link validity to 72 hours instead of 24?

Tags: apex, passwords, reset-password

I have a requirement to send a reset password link from the apex code. By default, the reset password link which is sent over the email is valid for 24 hours. Can I change that to 72 hours? I am skeptical about if we can change this. If not, is there any workaround for this?

**PS**
I have already checked the settings in the password policies.
I also went through [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=resetting_and_expiring_passwords.htm&type=5) help article but it doesn't say if we can customize it or not.

Comment: Out of the box - no. To change the semantics of reset password, you have to custom code the whole thing yourself.

Comment: @identigral Thanks, that's the last option, but let's see if someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible as this is hard-coded into the salesforce platform. See this help article:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390510&type=1

Thanks

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.